# Other widgets show, but not Button?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm working thru an example in *Tkinter GUI Application Development Hotshot* from Packt Pubs, using python 3.3 & tkinter 8.5 on Ubuntu 13.10.

Here is a small relevant portion of the code I'm having problems with:

```
import tkinter as tk

<snip>

def on_find():
    t2 = tk.Toplevel(root)
    t2.geometry('262x65+200+250')
    t2.transient(root)
    tk.Label(t2, text="Find all: ").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='e')
    v = tk.StringVar()
    e = tk.Entry(t2, width=25, textvariable=v)
    e.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=2, pady=2, sticky='we')
    e.focus_set()
    c = tk.IntVar()
    tk.Checkbutton(t2, text='Ignore case', variable=c).grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='e', padx=2, pady=2)
    tk.Button(t2, text='Find all', underline=0, command=lambda: search_for(v.get(),     c.get(), textPad, t2, e)).grid(row=2, column=1, sticky='e+w', padx=2, pady=2)

<snip>
```

Specifically, I'm having problems with the Button widget in the last line.  It's not showing up in the popup window at all.  The Label, the Text box, the Checkbutton - all there.  Just not the Button, and I'm not really sure why.

Comment: Maybe you have error in Button definiton. Do you get error message (trackback) in terminal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two errors:

- in `Checkbutton`: it should be `sticky` in place of `ticky`
- in `Button`: it should be `'ew'` in place `'e+w'`

Next time run program in terminal to get error message (trackback)

Comment: The 'ticky' was a typo... but the 'ew' did the trick.  Thanks!